# July 2013 upcoming change: Cannot create multiple create actions for the same Open Graph object. Explanation?

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph

In their blog post about upcoming breaking changes
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

FB writes:
We are no longer allowing multiple create actions for the same Open Graph object, as documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/

I thought that meant that you could only define one action type as the create type, which would be reasonable, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that for each user, you can only create a single action instance!

On that page, they give the example of creating a recipe. Fair enough, but keeping with that example, what if you allow your users to create a recipe and include properties like recipe name? After the user creates a recipe with the "food" action property set to "banana bread", they can never create another recipe again (such as one with the action property set to "pizza.") I tried setting the "Create" property and confirmed that I couldn't create more than one instance of my action property. I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding? Is the solution to just avoid marking your create action?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not like for each user you can only create one action-object pair. 
As per my understanding The doc mean to say you can only define one action of create type to each object. for example from the doc, `recipe` object has one `create action` ie `write`, now recipe object can not have any other action of create type something like may be `add` action which can add a new recipe in turn creating a recipe object. Putting it in a line: **Among the all actions attached with an Object only one action should be creating the object.**

Comment: I thought that it meant the same thing at first, but, testing it out after marking an action as the create action and then trying to use it, I get the following error returned:

"A [actionname] action for this object already exists."

After going back in and removing the listing of the action as the create action, it works again for creating new action instances. Looks like unfortunately it may be what I described above.

Comment: Note, you have to enable the July 2013 migrations to see this.

Comment: Does this mean you cannot "Cook" and then "Recommend" a recipe? Why not? Did I get it wrong?